# still look for Struts after moving to spring

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, struts1

I've just moved an app (dev on NetBeans and run on glassfish) from Struts 1.3.10 to Spring MVC. I changed my coding, removed all Struts related things, test it in my testing environment. Everything works fine. Then I move the all stuff to production environment. It also works fine. But I notice when starting glassfish, there are a lot of warning on unable to find some Struts renderers (all are "Unable to load class org.apache.struts.faces.component...." or "Unable to load class org.apache.struts.faces.renderer......".

I checked over and over again my project folder. I searched the word Struts in the folder. Nothing is related to Struts. I checked the domain.xml of my dev and production environment. Nothing is mentioned about Struts. Though the app is working fine with Spring now, I would like to get rid of those Struts warning log. Did I miss anything in my checking?

Comment: I would say yes, you did.

Comment: @DaveNewton, can you tell me what I've missed. As said, I've searched Struts in the project folder. After your reply, I've also searched html:, logic:, bean: in my JSPs and nothing was found. I never use org.apache.struts.faces in my project. Also, the warning log only appears in my production glassfish, never in dev.

Comment: Don't know, I'd have to poke around the server and your app. Check the actual deployment, grep your XML and Java for "face" ignoring case, etc.